# Setting up Multithreading in Spotfire

Tags: multithreading, ironpython, spotfire

I am trying to set up a multi threading code for Spotfire. I was wondering if anyone can help me set up a basic one, since I couldnt find any place explaining how to do it. I was able to find this [thread](https://community.tibco.com/questions/execute-iron-python-async-not-application-thread) talking about setting one up, but I couldnt understand how to set up the code. Also I am using Spotfire v7.11 in case future versions have made it easier to have multithreading work.

I have tried creating a simple thread function as seen [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/threading.shtml) but that kept crashing the code. Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: For which reason do you want it to be multi-threaded? If this is for performance reasons, maybe you can optimize your code with a profiler or things like this.

Comment: @txemsukr I just have a huge data file that i have to go through and replace some values in. So I was thinking about breaking up the data file into multiple parts and doing it that way to improve the speed that way.

Comment: I think that you have better alternatives than setting up multithreading. You have to check where is the bottleneck, maybe it is just on reading the file, on IO speed, then multithreading won't help. Maybe you can import the whole file in spotfire and have the column you want with a calculated column (so instead of replacing values, just have a column with the new values you want).

Comment: @txemsukr is setting up mutlithreading on spotfire that complicated?

Comment: just for future knowledge

Comment: I've never done it before, and I'm unsure that this feature would, even partially, be supported. I think that you should explore a bit more, like managing your PC resources while running the script for example, before diving in the unknown and setting up something that may not solve your problem. If your problem is that only one core is fully used while the screen is running, then you can start envisaging it, but first be sure that this is not a memory or IO speed limiting factor.